# I want to run my java app on a tomcat server, but I have a problem

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, dynamic

I want to run my java app on a tomcat server. It's a Maven Project initially.
Here is the architecture of the project:
[image]

As you can see, I can successfully export the project in a .war, which should, hopefully, enable me to get the app deployed on tomcat.
However, when I copy paste the .war file in the ./webapp of tomcat, it successfully deploy the application, meaning that there is a directory created with all my classes and stuff (as you can see in the following image):

[image]

However, when I try to access my app. I receive this error:
[image]

I tried a lot of things, from changing the jdk to changing the version of the tomcat server. But nothing seems to work. Any ideas that might help this situation?

I would sincerely appreciate any help or insight you might have on this issue.
Sincerely,

I tried to update the versions and create a new project altogether, hoping that it would work...But then I would have another problem, mainly the dynamic web module that would not get ticked in project facets (but is ticked in the original project).

Here are the error messages:

ECHEC - L'application pour le chemin de contexte [/stripe-paiement] n'a pas pu être démarrée
ECHEC - L'exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Echec de démarrage du composant [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/stripe-paiement]]] a été rencontrée

Or in english:

FAILURE - The application with context path [/stripe-paiement] could not be started.
FAILURE - The exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/stripe-paiement]]] was encountered

Comment: You will get more clues if you look in the log catalina.out

Comment: Do you mean this :

Comment: If that's an extract you've posted above, then yes, although a. we need to see what led up to it, i.e. full stack trace and b. it's a problem if it's in French

Comment: Ok , just checked your image does have around 9 mb for .war size, but, take a look at the web.xml DTD or Schema version in the project and see if it is the same version as the e.g. "manager" application in your server! It may be your maven app was made for Glassfish or is javax when it should be Jakarta .The Tomcat 9 and older are javax , Tomcat 10 and newer are Jakarta. You may need to do refactoring of code and libraries for both code and web.xml DTD and Schema.